# Domain Controller Acting As NTP but using NT5DS

Tags: domain-controller, ntp

We are currently using a PDC setup for our domain controllers to be our NTP server but in the REGEDIT it is showing type NT5DC instead of NTP. The issue that I am having is that our non domain computers are not able to synchronize with our ntp server. I have done all the pings to verify that communication is available and it is. Is this because our domain controllers are set to NT5DC instead of NTP or is that a non-issue?

Comment: What does `w32tm /query /configuration` show on the DC from an elevated command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that "NT5DC" means that the NTP client is going to use the domain hierarchy to discover and secure NTP communications. This is the correct setting for windows ntp clients that are NOT the PDC emulator in the root domain.

The PDC Emulator in the root domain should be set to NTP and pointed to a trusted external NTP source (0.pool.ntp.org).
*Example:* w32tm /config /manualpeerlist:0.pool.ntp.org 1.pool.ntp.org /syncfromflags:manual /reliable:yes /update

In short these settings refer to the NTP Client functionality, not NTP Server functionality.

If you can't pull NTP data from your DC's from non windows clients, my first stop would be ping (you've done), then either temporarily disable the Windows Firewall, or open port 123/UDP on the DC in question, and test again.

Ref: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/windows-time-service/How-the-Windows-Time-Service-Works

Answer (score 0):

I have a group policy applied to the PDC. The type "NTP" is set for the NTP-client, but there is also a policy to "activate" the server. See [my GPO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQVJW.jpg)